# Referencing subclass in static variable

Tags: java, deadlock

Intellij inspection tool warns about referencing a subclass in a static variable isn't a good practice because it can cause a deadlock. The following text is used:

> This inspection reports classes that refer to their own subclasses in
> their static initializers or in static fields. Such references can
> cause JVM-level deadlocks in multithreaded environment, when one
> thread tries to load superclass and another thread tries to load
> subclass at the same time.

The following examples demonstrates that:

```java
class Generator {

    public static Generator fiveGenerator = new FixedGenerator(5);

    public static Generator sixGenerator = new FixedGenerator(6);

    int generateNumber() {
        //some generation code
        return 1;
    }

    private static class FixedGenerator
            extends Generator {

        FixedGenerator(int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        @Override
        int generateNumber() {
            return this.num;
        }

        private int num;
    }
}
```

Note that:

- `FixedGenerator` class is and should be private.
- `fiveGenerator` and `sixGenerator` are and should be public.

On that I have two questions:

- Is it a bad practice? Why? How can a deadlock be caused by this?
- What's the right way to equivalent code implement that?

Comment: Hard to guess what this code should do, so hard to advice. I don't see here any danger for deadlock. There is no synchronisation in this class.

Comment: "As I know referencing a subclass in a static variable isn't a good practice because it can cause a deadlock". That doesn't add up to me - what is your source (or the reasoning behind the statement)?

Comment: Sadly, this is a good question with some poor answers, from people who don't seem to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not cause any deadlock.
Deadlock is related to concurrency and you don't have concurrency.
You *could* have an initialization issue but you will not either as you don't have cycle as `FixedGenerator()` invokes `Generator()` but `Generator()` doesn't invoke `FixedGenerator()`.

> Is it a bad practice?

It is as classes should not reference/know their subclasses.

> What's the right way to equivalent code implement that?

You could avoid inheritancy in the private class.
As alternative, you could favor the composition over the inheritancy.